# How to format columns in excel?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to ask the community for help on formatting a column in *Excel* using *OpenpyXL 3.0.3*.

One of my program creates a CSV file and I want to convert to *XL* with all the formatting and save it as *XL*.
My output files can have more than 500K Rows and 10 to 12 columns

My Sample csv Data:

```
trans_key,sqnc_nbr
201712127590004004159,10
201712112310000101519,23
201712127590000209181,10
201712190250000708589,34
```

I don't know how to format column B to number

```py
with open('/home/Pythonscripts/testcsv.csv', 'r') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
data = list(reader)

for i in data:
ws.append(i)  

wb.save("/home/Pythonscripts/csvtoxl.xlsx")  

from openpyxl import load_workbook
  wb = load_workbook( '/home/Pythonscripts/csvtoxl.xlsx' )
  ws = wb[ wb.sheetnames[0] ]
  cell11 = ws.cell(2, 1)
  cell11.number_format = '0'
wb.save( '/home/talendsvcacc/eJob/Rewards/Pythonscripts/csvtoxl_sample.xlsx' )
wb.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only issue just iterate over the cells in the column setting them to the correct format.

```
for col_cells in worksheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2):
    for cell in col_cells:
        cell.number_format = '#,##0'
```